# Nested conditional statements based on criteria from multiple columns and rows

Tags: r, conditional-statements, sapply

I am trying to create a matrix of species co-occurrences. I have a dataframe b.d

```
species <- c("A","A","F","H","D","E","C","D")
ID <- c("a1", "a2", "f1", "h1", "d1", "e1", "c1", "d2")
loc <- c(1,2,2,1,3,5,2,3)
time <- c("8:00","9:00","9:00","10:00","12:00","12:00","1:00","2:00")
cn <- c(1:8)
data.frame(species, ID, loc, time, cn)

species  ID  loc  time cn
1   A    a1   1   8:00  1
2   A    a2   2   9:00  2
3   F    f1   2   9:00  3
4   B    b1   1  10:00  4
5   D    d1   3  12:00  5
6   E    e1   5  12:00  6
7   C    c1   2   1:00  7
8   D    d2   3   2:00  8
```

I want to create a conditional "criteria" for co-occurrence such that:

if species [x] is found within +/- 1 location and within 1 hour of either:

2 species A | 1 species A and 1 species B | 1 species C

then, count those species as co-occurring and paste(species, ID, sep="."), if not, 0.

My code looks something like this:

```
instance <- as.data.frame(with(b.d, sapply(cn, function(x)
    ifelse(abs(loc- loc[x]) <=1 & abs(difftime(time, time[x], units = "mins")) <= 60 &
        ((b.d$species[x]=="A" & b.d$species[x]=="A")
        | (b.d$species[x]=="A" & b.d$species[x]=="B")
               | b.d$species[x]=="C"), 
           paste(b.d$species,b.d$ID,sep="."),0))))
```

And I want to end up with a matrix with cn(=8) number of cols and rows, where each column contains the species that were observed together based on the criteria. So,

```
    V1    V2    V3    V4   V5    V6    V7   V8
1  A.a1  A.a1  A.a1   0     0     0    0     0
2  A.a2  A.a2  A.a2  A.a2   0     0    0     0
3  F.f1  F.f1  F.f1  F.f1   0     0    0     0
4  0     B.b1  B.b1  B.b1   0     0    0     0
5  0      0     0     0     0     0    0     0
6  0      0     0     0     0   E.e1  E.e1  E.e1
7  0      0     0     0     0   C.c1  C.c1  C.c1
8  0      0     0     0     0   D.d2  D.d2  D.d2
```

The code above works for the location and time criteria, but the species[x] criteria is messed up somehow. Only the first argument (species[x]=="A") is being applied and the rest results in zeros. I think that the sapply function is reading species[x] row by row so that species[x] can only represent 1 species at a time, how do I get around this so that each row is being checked against multiple other rows? so that species[x] can represent a combination of species?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Patricia, can you please clarify why you think the output needs to be a `cn x cn` matrix? Based on your criteria, a species can only ever be observed as co-occuring with species `A`,`B` or `C`. Thus, why do we even need to consider any other species? Please try explaining your logic again.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for the response. I wanted the output to be in a `cn x cn` matrix because I eventually wanted to create a df from the co-occurrence matrix with counts of the number of times each pair of species co-occurs. I guess the output doesn't need to be a matrix - it would be better if I could end up with a data frame with two columns representing the species pairs co-occurring. So, `A.a1` with `A.a2`, `A.a1` with `F.f1`, etc. Does that make sense?